# Deploying nestjs server created in NX monorepo

Tags: angular, nestjs, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I have a NX monorepo containing mostly Angular front end code that we've since added a express server and I'm trying to figure out how to deploy it. The problem is how to separate out the vendor based code from node modules that's just for the server application.

Typically with a typical Angular app we have a vendor file containing all the 3rd party dependencies, and historically for are server apps they would have their own package.json that we can just install locally at build. I'm assuming their is a way to solve this but I haven't found any reference to it. I'd really rather not take the entire node modules folder and place it on the server, nor create a separate package.json that only references the server code.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Not inside of a monorepo it isn't, if you aren't familiar with nx I suggest checking it out [nx](https://nx.dev/) .

Comment: I'm not familiar with NX, I'll check it out though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution I found is that there is an configuration for the builder in angular.json. If you set

```
"externalDependencies": "none"
```

then the output will be a single file containing all the dependencies included.

Comment: did you run into these types of warnings from build command? `Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted`

Comment: I'm getting a lot of `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '......'`, and it all seems to be related to NestJS modules :/. Has anybody been able to do this ?