# How to deploy a NestJS application which is in a Nx monorepo with CI CD?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, backend

I am working on a NestJS application which is part of an Nx monorepo. I tried Vercel, but it conflicted with the deployment of UI apps. Heroku is paid now. I want to learn how to deploy a NestJS application with CI/CD enabled. Whenever there is a push to the main branch, the code should be automatically deployed like NextJS via Vercel. I have been stuck at this for a few days and have tried AWS's EC2, Beanstalk, and Serverless. I am doing something wrong, which is why I keep failing. It would be great if I get a resource on the same. I appreciate any help provided.

I tried to follow [Deploying nestjs server created in NX monorepo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972978/deploying-nestjs-server-created-in-nx-monorepo), but it is completely a different thing.